# Does this valgrind output mean there is a memory leak? (renamed question)

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

### *(original title: Possible memory leak problem)*

I write two pieces of c programs like following, during memcheck process using Valgrind, a lot of mem leak information is given.

```
int
GetMemory(int framewidth,
          int frameheight,
          int SR/*, int blocksize*//*,int ALL_REF_NUM*/)
{
    //int i,j;
    int memory_size = 0;
    //int refnum = ALL_REF_NUM;
    int input_search_range = SR;

    memory_size += get_mem2D(&curFrameY, frameheight, framewidth);
    memory_size += get_mem2D(&curFrameU, frameheight>>1, framewidth>>1);
    memory_size += get_mem2D(&curFrameV, frameheight>>1, framewidth>>1);

    memory_size += get_mem3D(&prevFrameY, refnum, frameheight, framewidth);// to allocate reference frame buffer accoding to the reference frame number 
    memory_size += get_mem3D(&prevFrameU, refnum, frameheight>>1, framewidth>>1);
    memory_size += get_mem3D(&prevFrameV, refnum, frameheight>>1, framewidth>>1);

    memory_size += get_mem2D(&mpFrameY, frameheight, framewidth);
    memory_size += get_mem2D(&mpFrameU, frameheight>>1, framewidth>>1);
    memory_size += get_mem2D(&mpFrameV, frameheight>>1, framewidth>>1);

    memory_size += get_mem2D(&searchwindow, input_search_range*2 + blocksize, input_search_range*2 + blocksize);// to allocate search window according to the searchrange

    /*memory_size +=*/ get_mem1D(/*&SAD_cost, height, width*/);
    // memory_size += get_mem2D(&searchwindow, 80, 80);// if searchrange is 32, then only 32+1+32+15 pixels is needed in each row and col, therefore the range of 
    // search window is enough to be set to 80 !

    memory_size += get_mem2Dint(&all_mv, height/blocksize, width/blocksize);

    return 0;

}


void
FreeMemory(int refno)
{
    free_mem2D(curFrameY);
    free_mem2D(curFrameU);
    free_mem2D(curFrameV);

    free_mem3D(prevFrameY,refno);
    free_mem3D(prevFrameU,refno);
    free_mem3D(prevFrameV,refno);

    free_mem2D(mpFrameY);
    free_mem2D(mpFrameU);
    free_mem2D(mpFrameV);

    free_mem2D(searchwindow);
    free_mem1D();
    free_mem2Dint(all_mv);
}

void free_mem1D()
{
    free(SAD_cost);
}
```

Now I hope to make sure where are the possible problems in my program? 
Here I may post some valgrind information to let you know about the actual error information.

```
==29105==    by 0x804A906: main (me_search.c:1480)
==29105== 
==29105== 
==29105== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29105==     in use at exit: 124,088 bytes in 18 blocks
==29105==   total heap usage: 37 allocs, 21 frees, 749,276 bytes allocated
==29105== 
==29105== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x804885E: GetMemory (me_search.c:117)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 352 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 18
==29105==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==29105==    by 0x409537E: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==29105==    by 0x409544B: fopen@@GLIBC_2.1 (iofopen.c:107)
==29105==    by 0x804A660: main (me_search.c:1439)
==29105== 
==29105== 584 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x8048724: GetMemory (me_search.c:106)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 584 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x8048747: GetMemory (me_search.c:107)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 584 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x8048809: GetMemory (me_search.c:114)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 584 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x804882C: GetMemory (me_search.c:115)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 584 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x804A4F8: get_mem3D (me_search.c:1393)
==29105==    by 0x804879B: GetMemory (me_search.c:110)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 584 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x804A4F8: get_mem3D (me_search.c:1393)
==29105==    by 0x80487C9: GetMemory (me_search.c:111)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 1,168 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 9 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x8048701: GetMemory (me_search.c:105)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 1,168 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 10 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x80487E6: GetMemory (me_search.c:113)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 1,168 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 18
==29105==    at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105==    by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105==    by 0x804A4F8: get_mem3D (me_search.c:1393)
==29105==    by 0x804876D: GetMemory (me_search.c:109)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
==29105== 
==29105== 6,336 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 12 of 18
==29105==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==29105==    by 0x804A25C: get_mem1D (me_search.c:1295)
==29105==    by 0x8048866: GetMemory (me_search.c:119)
==29105==    by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a memory leak? What have you tried to find it? What are you trying to accomplish? What is this code *supposed* to do? Please add some more information to help the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Because I found I can not edit the post in my firefox browser under linux environment. therefore, I firstly past the program, and then go to another computer to edit this post.

Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Have you verified that FreeMemory is being caled at all?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I am a new c programmer, therefore, I might make some naive mistakes.

Comment: If you are running it in a console, you should add some `printf` statements within FreeMemory so that you can make sure it is being called.

Comment: Can you please post the code for get_mem2D, get_mem3D etc and also for all your free functions?

Comment: @Jay http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/doc/ldec/html/memalloc_8h.html

Comment: @Mai I think you should try editing your main function so that it looks like this. `GetMemory(10,10,10); FreeMemory(ALL_REF_NUM);` Although that code won't work, because currently, the `refnum` is an invalid variable in the `GetMemory();` function

Comment: Once your main is only those two lines. Run valgrind on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the two records marked "definitely lost", becuase those are *certainly* memory leaks:

```
==29105== 1,168 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 18
==29105== at 0x402425F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==29105== by 0x804A296: get_mem2D (me_search.c:1315)
==29105== by 0x804A4F8: get_mem3D (me_search.c:1393)
==29105== by 0x804876D: GetMemory (me_search.c:109)
==29105== by 0x804A757: main (me_search.c:1456)
```

What this indicates is that the memory allocated by `calloc()` on line 1315 of `me_search.c` got leaked.  This happened when `get_mem2D()` was called by line 1393 of `me_search.c` in `get_mem3D()`, which in turn was called by line 109 in `GetMemory()`, which was called by line 1456 in `main()`.

Those line numbers should be enough to start working out *why* it got leaked.